# Why is my implementation of IExceptionHandler not returning the error response?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, asp.net-web-api2

I am building a web api using ASP.NET and F#. I have an implementation of IExceptionHandler.

```
type DefaultExceptionHandler() =

let mapExceptionTypetoHttpStatusCode (ex:Exception) : HttpStatusCode =
    match ex with
    | :? ArgumentException -> HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
    | _ -> HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError

interface IExceptionHandler with
    member x.HandleAsync (context:ExceptionHandlerContext, cancellationToken:CancellationToken) =
        let request = context.Request
        let ex = context.Exception
        let httpStatusCode = mapExceptionTypetoHttpStatusCode ex

        context.Result <- { new IHttpActionResult with member x.ExecuteAsync(token:CancellationToken) = Task.FromResult(request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatusCode, ex)) }
        Task.FromResult(0) :> Task
```

It is registered at startup.

```
type Global() =
inherit System.Web.HttpApplication() 

static member RegisterWebApi(config: HttpConfiguration) =
    // Configure routing
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        "DefaultApi", // Route name
        "api/{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        { controller = "{controller}"; id = RouteParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    ) |> ignore


    config.Services.Replace(typeof<IExceptionHandler>, new DefaultExceptionHandler())

member x.Application_Start() =
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(Action<_> Global.RegisterWebApi)
```

I can debug and see that the code is traversed, but the response returned is not the response set in the handler. I am sure it is something simple that I am overlooking and which is not triggering a compiler error, but I have thus far been unable to ascertain the problem. Am I not setting the `context.Result` correctly?

Hopefully one of you F# gurus will immediately see my error. Thank you for taking the time to read this far.

Comment: That `Task.FromResult(0)` expression looks suspicious. Try to execute the entire method body inside a task, or for more F#ness, implement it in an `async` work-flow, and convert it to a `Task` as the return expression.

Comment: For a similar example, this might help: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/12/web-api-raygun-error-handler

Comment: @MarkSeemann Thank you for the response. I posted an answer below detailing what was causing my issue. I have posted another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699555/what-is-the-correct-way-to-return-an-empty-task-when-implementing-message-hand) attempting to address the concern you raised regarding the use of `Task.FromResult(0)`. Thanks for the link as it lead to my discovering your "Functional Architecture with F#" course, which is now at the top of my queue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the *problem* turned out to be (embarrassingly) simple and I will post it here in case others run into a similar issue while using the F# Web API template as a learning mechanism.

It arose from a misunderstanding of the template. As it currently exists the template delivers the response by convention using an `index.html` file located in the project root.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Car List App</title>
    <link href="./Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <h2 class="sub-header">All Cars</h2>
    <table id="cars" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>#</td>
                <td>Make</td>
                <td>Model</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody />
    </table>
</div>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="./Scripts/main.js"></script>
```

Some JavaScript called from within `index.html` is what actually executed the call to the controller.

```
$(function () {
    var uri = 'api/cars';

    $.getJSON(uri)
        .done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                $('<tr><td>' + (key + 1) + '</td><td>' + item.make + '</td><td>' + item.model + '</td></tr>')
                    .appendTo($('#cars tbody'));
            });
        });
});
```

Since the JS is expecting objects with the above properties, when it received the error response it ignored it and displayed the empty `index.html` page.

Rookie, mistake. Hopefully this saves someone a few minutes of their life.