# What is the correct way to return an "empty task" when implementing message handlers such as IExceptionHandler or IExceptionLogger in F#?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, f#, asp.net-web-api2

In C# when implementing these handlers I would do something similar to this,

```
public class DefaultExceptionHandler : IExceptionHandler
{
    public Task HandleAsync(ExceptionHandlerContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        context.Result = new ErrorActionResult(context.Request, context.Exception);

        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}
```

When implementing the same interface in F# I did the following,

```
type DefaultExceptionHandler() =

    let mapExceptionTypetoHttpStatusCode (ex:Exception) : HttpStatusCode =
        match ex with
        | :? ArgumentException -> HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
        | _ -> HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError

    interface IExceptionHandler with
        member x.HandleAsync (context:ExceptionHandlerContext, cancellationToken:CancellationToken) =
            let request = context.Request
            let ex = context.Exception
            let httpStatusCode = mapExceptionTypetoHttpStatusCode ex

            context.Result <- { new IHttpActionResult with member x.ExecuteAsync(token:CancellationToken) = Task.FromResult(request.CreateErrorResponse(httpStatusCode, ex)) }
            Task.FromResult(0) :> Task
```

The compiler was requiring the cast `Task.FromResult(0) :> Task` which is not required in the C# example. What is the correct and idiomatic way to return from the `ExecuteAsync` method in F#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The F# compiler requires a cast, because in F# there is no automatic conversion to supertypes (or to anything else for that matter). This is a very useful feature of F#, it guards against a whole class of mistakes, where conversion to supertype would change the meaning of the program.

So having this cast operator in your program is completely fine. If you don't feel like typing too much, you can also ask the compiler to infer the type for you:

```
let a: obj = "abcd"          // No cast - compile-time error
let b: obj = "abcd" :> obj   // Explicit cast to supertype
let c: obj = "abcd" :> _     // Explicit cast to inferred supertype
```

If you really want to do away with the cast, you can use a task-creating method that returns a `Task` right away, instead of `Task<T>`, which would need to be cast. One such method is `Task.Run( Action )`:

```
let t = Task.Run( fun() -> () )   // t: Task
```

But this is way more wasteful.

Comment: Thank you. I'm fine with the cast as is. I wanted to make sure it was appropriate and idiomatic. I'm really liking F# more and more as I penetrate the veil.

Comment: You could also use the `upcast` operator if you don't like typing colons and angle-brackets.